# Night trains from Cairo to Luxor/Aswan?

Tags: trains, egypt, cairo

Is it possible to book on-line the night train from Cairo to Luxor or Aswan? Where can I find a timetable and summary of available compartments?

On a side note, if and how much do these trains get delayed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

Entering "train from cairo to luxor" in Google found me [this link](http://www.seat61.com/Egypt.htm#.UTDTojA4ssJ) (first) and [this link](http://www.egyptindependent.com/node/2492) (second).

You can book online [here](http://www.seat61.com/Egypt.htm#Cairo%20-%20Luxor%20-%20Aswan). The link explicitly gives prices for foreigners.